# Using web2py, jQuery and ajax, how do you post to a database?

Tags: ajax, database, jquery, web2py

Using web2py I am trying to use ajax to put data into a table in my database, but I'm needing a bit of help.

Here is the function I am using (it currently has dummy data in the data section, rather than being passed data from a form):

```
function submitData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "requests",
        data: {
                    id: 1, 
                    user_id:111, 
                    bottle_image:'',
                    bottle_name:'JJjman',
                    bottle_description:'Lol',
                    request_creationDate:'2000-01-01',
                    request_expiryDate:'2003-08-08', 
                    request_fulfilled:false
            },
        success: function(){
            alert('Posted data');
        }
    });
}
```

I have a html button with this function attached to its 'onclick', but at the moment all it does is reload the page and not pass any data onto the database. The success alert is also coming up.

Firebug is saying that the POST does contain all that data, but I'm not sure if the POST is actually going anywhere..

Am I missing any steps needed to actually pass this data to the database? Or could this just be that my data isn't all the right type for the database?

Cheers guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply sending a post from the browser won't do anything on the server unless you have code on the server to handle the data and insert it into the database.

I strongly recommend you read through the relevant parts of the [book](http://web2py.com/book) to learn how to do this. The [Overview](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#An-image-blog) chapter provides an introductory tutorial, including building an [image blog](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#An-image-blog) that involves modeling a database table and creating a form to post records to that table.

Review the [DAL](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer) chapter for details on modeling your database, the section on [`SQLFORM`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM) for details on creating forms associated with database tables, and the sections on [ajax](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax#The-ajax-function) and [components](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12/components-and-plugins#Components) for details on using Ajax to post forms.

The easiest way to do what you want would be something like this:

In /models/db.py:

```
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')

db.define_table('bottle',
    Field('user_id')
    Field('bottle_image'),
    Field('bottle_name'),
    Field('bottle_description', 'text'),
    Field('request_creationDate', 'date'),
    Field('request_expiryDate', 'date'),
    Field('request_fulfilled', 'boolean'),
    format='%(bottle_name)s')
```

In /controllers/default.py:

```
def index():
    return dict()

def add_bottle():
    return dict(form=SQLFORM(db.bottle).process())
```

In /views/default/add_bottle.load:

```
{{=form}}
```

In /views/default/index.html:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

{{=LOAD('default', 'add_bottle.load', ajax=True)}}
```

Then go to /yourapp/default/index, and you will see a form, which will post records to the database via Ajax.